# Сравнение и комбинирование данных из 2х массивов

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Есть два одинаковых по структуре, но разных по значениям и количеству ключей многомерных массива, 3-уровневых, следующего вида:

```
array(
   'tournaments' => array(
                    0 => array(
                         'id' => '5',
                         'name' => 'VI тур. Не допустить...'),
                    ), 
                    ...
   'tanks' => array(
                    0 => array(
                     'id' => 1,
                     'fullname' => 'T-150',
                     'level' => 'VI',
                    ),
                    1 => array(
                      'id' => 2,
                      'fullname' => 'T-50', 
                      'level' => 'IV'
                   )
                   ...
);
```

Один содержит текущие данные. Второй обновленные. Требуется получить третий, выходной массив со всеми ключами и их значениям которые изменились или добавились. В целом эта задача решается рекурсивным обходом функцией arrayRecursiveDiff вот отсюда (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876435/recursive-array-diff), НО есть одна проблема - на выходе нужно оставить поля-сиблинги, пОля которое изменилось. Кроме того добавить сюда еще одно поле с булевым значением. Так как это массив будет передаваться на обработку следующей функции, в которой нужно будет проверить изменено поле либо дабавлено и в зависимости от этого либо insert в БД либо update.Есть у кого какие идеи или предложения? Подумайте за меня пожалуйста, застрял, заблудился! Родина вас не забудет =).

**UPD1:** Вот собственно сама функция рекурсивного сравнения массивов. Как в контексте этой функции можно решить эту задачу?

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) { // извлекаем различия между новыми и старыми данными
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) { // перебераем новый массив данных в цикле, сопоставляя его элементы со старыми
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) { // если поле существует в новом масиве
      if (is_array($mValue)) { // если это поле так же является массивом
        $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]); // рекурсивный анализ соответствия вложенных ключей
        if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { // если найдены несоответствия
                $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff;  // кладем их во вложенный выходной массив
            }
      } else { // если значение поля не является массивом выполняем заветное действие
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) { // проверяем не совпадают ли ключи, и если совпадают          
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; // записываем несоответствие полей в выходной массив
          // тут нужно получить сиблинг поля
          // и вставить поле с логической переменной
        }
      } 
    } else { // если поле не существует в новом массиве
      $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; // просто записываем значение поля
    }
  }
  return $aReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант могу предложить доп. поля в третьем массиве с указанием 0,1 изменено поле, не изменено или добавлено новое.

```
    array(
       'tournaments' => array(
                        0 => array(
                             'id' => '5',
                             'name' => 'VI тур. Не допустить...'),
                        ),
   'tournamentsStatus' => array(
                    0 => array(
                         'id' => '0',
                         'name' => '1'),
                    ),
```